# Unable to perform any query to Mysql server on Azure from local php server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, azure, laravel-5.5

I am able to establish connection to mysql on Azure from local server. Then I am trying to get data from users table but it is failing. I tried using mysqli and also pdo connections. In any case it is failing. Below is the screenshot of failure. Please give me a solution.

I am using Laravel 5.5.

**In laravel controller :**

```
if (DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
   {
    return 'Connected to the DB: ' . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
   }
```

this connection is established successfully and returning db name

But when tried to query like this, it is throwing error:

```
if (DB::connection()->getDatabaseName())
   {
     return DB::select('select * from `users`');
   }
```

**ERROR MESSAGE :**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  (SQL: select * from `users`) in file C:\SIRI-22\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 664
```

The same code is working fine when connected to local mysql server.

[image: Exception message]

**AS I AM NOT ALLOWED TO POST ANSWER TO MY QUESTION, I AM POSTING SOLUTION TO THIS ISSUE HERE:**

I resolved the issue. It is explained in the comments section of azure website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl).

**Explanation :**

You might experience problems if you're trying to connect to Azure Database for MySQL over SSL from PHP through MySQLi or PDO. The problem in both cases is that the SSL certificates used by Azure Database for MySQL do not match the hostnames of the servers you're connecting to, and hence server certificate verification fails. (Many other clients will happily connect over SSL without verifying the server certificate, which only makes it harder to figure out what is wrong.)

Fortunately, this can be solved if you're running at least PHP 5.6.16 for MySQLi or PHP v7.1.4 for PDO and you're using the MySQL Native Driver--and Azure App Service meets these requirements. For MySQLi, you will need to add the MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT flag when you connect. For PDO, you will need to set the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT option to false when you connect.

See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68344 and https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71003 for details.

**This is explained by Warlock. Thanks to him !**

Comment: Please show us the code you used and the error message - in TEXT.  Not everyone can read images and remember that stackoverflow is also a resource for others looking for the same error message.  They won't find it in an image.

Comment: @LornaMitchell I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Had you check your Azure Firewall connection of your MySQL server, since Microsoft Azure doesn't allow any external connection by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your query builder. You can try

```
DB::table("users")->get();
```

Comment: There is no error in it. I am using basic raw query which is correct. I resolved the issue which was fixed by php guys in the stable release of php version 7.1.11. Thanks.

Comment: Is that so? Good for you brother.